# How to protect tagging apps from being disabled?

Tags: facebook, tagging, photos

I tried making two-three tagging apps that creates photos like , What my friends are scared of, It has the name and the picture of my friends and it asks them if they want to post too.

but still somehow when my apps get viral, Facebook deletes it.

https://apps.facebook.com/job_checker/

here is my newest (test app)

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the Facebook Statement of Rights and Responsibilities.

> Point 5.9 "You will not tag users or send email invitations to
>   non-users without their consent."

Also read their examples and explanations on authentic tagging.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/photos/

Your app seems to do exactly what they are trying to prevent.

Comment: So just adding a checkbox with " Tag your friends while uploading photo" will work ?

Comment: No, the problem is you're tagging other people without their knowledge or consent. As it says in that link: 

"As a best practice, we encourage developers to avoid providing users with the option to tag their friends in apps which generate images containing lists of friends."

I'd suggest you look at a solution that doesn't involve tagging. You can still add photos/albums on the user's behalf, you're just going to have to come up with a different way to grab their friend's attention.

Comment: There are like thousands of apps that tagg like 80apps.com.

Why don't they get banned ?

Comment: Perhaps they don't get that much negative feedback.